# How to access Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have created Docker images and deployed in k8s cluster with a minimum number of machines, setup one master and worker and both machines are up and running and talking to each other with the same VLAN network.

Please find the below pod and deployment services with described status

```
root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl describe services angular-service
Name:                     angular-service
Namespace:                pre-release
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"angular-service","namespace":"pre-release"},"spec":{"ports":[{"no...
Selector:                 app=frontend-app
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.96.151.155
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.6:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv   1/1     Running   0          51m

root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
angular-service   NodePort   10.96.151.155   <none>        80:31000/TCP   64m


root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl get pods --selector="app=frontend-app" --output=wide
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv   1/1     Running   0          52m   10.32.0.6   poc-worker2   <none>           <none>

root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl describe pods angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv
Name:         angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv
Namespace:    pre-release
Priority:     0
Node:         poc-worker2/10.0.0.6
Start Time:   Tue, 21 Jan 2020 05:15:49 +0000
Labels:       app=frontend-app
              pod-template-hash=7b8d45f48d
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.32.0.6
IPs:
  IP:           10.32.0.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d
Containers:
  frontend-app:
    Container ID:   docker://751a9fb4a5e908fa1a02eb0460ab1659904362a727a028fdf72489df663a4f69
    Image:          frontend-app:future-master-fix-d1afa608
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:0099587db89de9ef999a7d1f087d4781e73c491b17e89392e92b08d2f935ad27
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 21 Jan 2020 05:15:54 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-r67p7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-r67p7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-r67p7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Now the problem is I'm not able to access my application using a port, even though its not working in a web browser as well.

```
curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>

curl http://10.0.0.6:31000
```

Dockr file

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/hello-angular /usr/share/nginx/html
```

```
root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin# kubectl exec -it angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv curl 10.96.151.155:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.151.155 port 80: Connection refused
command terminated with exit code 7
```

```
root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin/kubernetes# kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -it --rm --command -- /bin/sh -c "wget 10.96.208.252:80;cat index.html"
Connecting to 10.96.208.252:80 (10.96.208.252:80)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |********************************|   593  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>AngularApp</title><base href="/"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"><link href="styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><app-root></app-root><script type="text/javascript" src="inline.720eace06148cc3e71aa.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.f20484b2fa4642e0dca8.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.11bc84b3b98cd0d00106.bundle.js"></script></body></html>pod "busybox" deleted
```

```
root@jenkins-linux-vm:/home/admin/kubernetes# kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -it --rm --command -- /bin/sh -c "wget 10.0.0.6:32331;cat index.html"
Connecting to 10.0.0.6:32331 (10.0.0.6:32331)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.6): Connection refused
cat: can't open 'index.html': No such file or directory
pod "busybox" deleted
pod pre-release/busybox terminated (Error)
```

Comment: where are you running your cluster? as you mentioned, it's working on web browser then what is the URL? is it `http://10.0.0.6:31000 `?

Comment: I guess you need to mention the namespace too while using `exec` commmand `kubectl exec -it -n  pre-release angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv`

Comment: Hi Kamol, typo error in browser also not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am taking a pre-built angular image from docker hub with thanks to `https://github.com/nheidloff/web-apps-kubernetes/tree/master/angular-app` we will use this image as baseline below.

**Create and deployment and service using below yamls**

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: angular-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: angular-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: angular-app
        image: nheidloff/angular-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: angular-app
  labels:
    run: angular-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    run: angular-app
```

**Run as below on your cluster to create the resources**

```
$ kubectl create -f Deployment.yaml
$ kubectl create -f Service.yaml
```

**Should result in below deployment and service configuration**

```
    $ kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES

pod/angular-app-694d97d56c-7m4x4   1/1     Running   0          8m23s   10.244.3.10   k8s-node-3   <none>           <none>

NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
service/angular-app   NodePort    10.96.150.136   <none>        80:32218/TCP,443:30740/TCP   8m23s   run=angular-app
service/kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      8d      <none>

NAME                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS    IMAGES                  SELECTOR
deployment.apps/angular-app   1/1     1            1           8m23s   angular-app   nheidloff/angular-app   run=angular-app

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS    IMAGES                  SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/angular-app-694d97d56c   1         1         1       8m23s   angular-app   nheidloff/angular-app   pod-template-hash=694d97d56c,run=angular-app
```

> From above we can see the pod is running node-3 , so identify the ip of node 3 
>   and we see that service has exposed below ports 32218/TCP and 30740/TCP

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-1   Ready    master   8d    v1.17.0   111.112.113.107   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
node-1     Ready    <none>   8d    v1.17.0   111.112.113.108   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
node-2     Ready    <none>   8d    v1.17.0   111.112.113.109   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
node-3     Ready    <none>   8d    v1.17.0   111.112.113.110   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
```

> So we need to access the app vi `node3:NodePort` i.e `111.112.113.110:32218` as url check below screen shot as well on how i access the app.

[image]

**I have below rules open on cluster level to allow browser access the apps on default NodePort range.**

> NOTE : Ingress    IPv4    TCP 30000 - 32767   0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Hi D.T, how to open Port range IPv4 TCP 30000 - 32767 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: If your kubernetes cluster is on company network you should contact your cluster admin to open this range for browser interaction.

Comment: Port 31000 i opened in Azure portal to access the default port

Comment: what result you get when you tryt o acess the app from another pod in cluster via service-ip or node ip like 

Service IP command `$ kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -it --rm --command -- /bin/sh -c "wget 10.96.150.136:80;cat index.html" `

Using Node IP command `$ kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -it --rm --command -- /bin/sh -c "wget 111.112.113.110:32218;cat index.html"` 

both should result `index.html           100% |********************************|   593  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved` and give you hint on where the data is being lost ..

Comment: Hi D.T i have updated outout for busybox test case.

Comment: what about output of second part !! i mean what result you get when you run same busybox test using `<Node IP>:<nodeport>` .. updated latest output of below commands as well .. `kubectl get all -o wide` and `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206362/discussion-between-d-t-and-anonymuss).

Comment: HI DT, Thanks lot finally its started to work, using the above approach.

Comment: Thanks Again to finish this discussion, i hope other folks who ever learning like me they will save lot of time using this your post.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure you are able to open your app by nodeport in browser you should try to establish that

> There are no rules blocking the default node-port range (i.e from port 30000 - to  port 32767) on security rules or firewall on cluster network.

For example verify you have below **security rule open on Cluster Network for nodeport range** to work in browser.

```
Ingress IPv4    TCP 30000 - 32767   0.0.0.0/0
```

Once you have confirmed you have no security group rule issue. I will take below approach to debug and find whats wrong with port reachablity at node level. perform a basic Test and check if i can get nginx web server installed and reachable on browser via node port:

Steps:

**Deploy a NGINX deployment** using below nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Verify deployment is up and running

```
$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml

$ kubectl get all
NAME                            READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-nginx-75897978cd-ptqv9   1/1     Running       0          32s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   4d11h

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/my-nginx   1/1     1            1           33s

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/my-nginx-75897978cd   1         1         1       33s
```

Now **create service to expose the nginx deployment** using below example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

Verify service is created and **identify the nodeport assigned** (since we did not provide any fixed port in service.yaml ( like below the node port is 32502)

```
$ kubectl apply -f service.yaml

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          4d11h
my-nginx     NodePort    10.96.174.234   <none>        8080:32502/TCP   12s
```

In addition to the nodeport **identify the ip of your master node** i.e 131.112.113.101 below

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-1   Ready    master   4d11h   v1.17.0   131.112.113.101   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
node-1     Ready    <none>   4d11h   v1.17.0   131.112.113.102   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
node-2     Ready    <none>   4d11h   v1.17.0   131.112.113.103   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-169-generic   docker://18.6.2
```

Now if you try to access the nginx application using the IP of your masternode with nodeport value like `<masternode>:<nodeport>` (i.e. 131.112.113.101:32502) in your browser you should get result similar to below

[image]

**Note**  the container port used on nginx.yaml and targetPort on service.yaml (i.e. 80) you should be able to figure out this for your app better. Hope this will help you understand the issue at your node/cluster level if any.

Comment: Hi D.T, i can able to run the Ngnix server in a browser, but why i am not able to access my own an angular application.

Comment: If you have tested above and nginx is working in browser then your cluster setup looks fine, if i were you i will go back to basic and try to figure out wats missing on angular-app docker file .. its better if you also share detail of docker file in use itself in the question details.

Comment: Hi D.T, thanks for the suggestion, i will update docker file here.

Comment: Is that correct docker file details you added ? .. are u sure that you are not missing exposing the port itself !! .. possible lines to add to your docker file ... ````# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80````

Comment: Hi D.T, i have added EXPOSE 80 in my docker file but still i am not able to access it in web browser

Comment: I will update a walk through steps below using one of the docker hub images and yamls below hope you are able to get it working then .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206358/discussion-between-d-t-and-anonymuss).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood what you are trying to do.

Below command is to open a bash shell in the pod:
`kubectl exec -it angular-deployment-7b8d45f48d-b59pv -- /bin/bash`

You can connect to a pod, then try curl.

Comment: But how to access application in a web browser

Comment: Did you manage to CURL your app when using the command above?

Comment: Hi Harsh, Yes your right I can able to enter inside an angular application using kubectl exec command with pod name

Comment: But When I tried with curl using the master machine IP address and Nodeport number like this http://Master_IP:Port it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The service is defined as NodePort type.

it is using nodeport: 31000

Try hitting the below url in your browser

http://HOSTNAME:31000

hostname could be any hostname of the cluster nodes

Comment: Hi EK, Sorry its not working when i trying hit the name of the IP or hostname

Comment: the app might be down inside the pod. share the container logs

Comment: No, My pod is running state only

Comment: you are able to access nginx using nodeport in browser. your app endpoint must not be responding

Comment: Yes i can able to access Nginx via Node Port, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot my application