# Access application deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have my image hosted on GCR.
I deployed my application on local Kubernetes cluster(mac).
This is my deployment file -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sv-premier
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sv-premier
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sv-premier
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: google-cloud-key
        secret:
          secretName: gcp-key
      containers:
      - name: sv-premier
        image: gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["echo", "Done deploying sv-premier"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: imagepullsecretkey
```

I am trying to access the application but I am not able to.
I created the service as -->

```
$ kubectl expose deployment sv-premier --port=8080 --target-port=8080
service/sv-premierleague exposed

$ kubectl get service sv-premier
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
sv-premier   ClusterIP   10.107.202.156   <none>        8080/TCP   58s
```

> $ kubectl get all -o wide

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/sv-premier-6b695d5fd7-l4995   1/1     Running   0          21h   10.1.0.45   docker-desktop   <none>           <none

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE   SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    8d    <none>
service/sv-premier   ClusterIP   10.107.202.156   <none>        8080/TCP   23m   app=sv-premier

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                    SELECTOR
deployment.apps/sv-premier   1/1     1            1           21h   sv-premier   gcr.io/sap-s4-proto/premiercore1:latest   app=sv-premier


NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                    SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/sv-premier-6b695d5fd7   1         1         1       21h   sv-premier   gcr.io/sap-s4-proto/premiercore1:latest   app=sv-premierleague,pod-template-hash=6b695d5fd7
```

> $ kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    master   8d    v1.15.5   192.168.65.3   <none>        Docker Desktop   4.19.76-linuxkit   docker://19.3.5
```

Now as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835323/how-to-access-kubernetes-deployment) in the accepted answer, I am trying to access my application like --
docker-desktop:NodePort i.e. 192.168.65.3:8080. But I am not able to.
[image]

Comment: Can you access it using: `kubernetes.docker.internal:8080` or `localhost:8080` when having loadbalancer deployed?

Comment: no.. I am doing using NodePort but not able to access

Answer (score 2):

Update your command to include the type to expose service on nodeport

`kubectl expose deployment sv-premier --port=8080 --type=NodePort`

Then your should try to reach the service using ..  ip:nodeport combination

> Are you using Google cloud ? The you should prefer service type=loadbalancer

When you create a Service of type LoadBalancer, a Google Cloud controller auto configures a network load balancer. Wait a minute for the controller to configure the network load balancer and generate a stable IP address. Use details from the loadbalncer to access the service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did -  kubectl expose deployment sv-premier --port=8080 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort. got the port - 

NAME               TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
sv-premier   NodePort   10.104.129.125   <none>        8080:32103/TCP   15s

now again i cannot access - docker-desktopIP:32103

Comment: even if loadbalancer type is used, we have to access using -- docker-desktopIP:loadBalancerPort... ?

Comment: No you should you the loadbalncer details

Comment: this is my loadbalancer -

NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
sv-premier   LoadBalancer   10.105.63.249   localhost     8080:31678/TCP   10m


i cannot access this --> 10.105.63.249:31678

hope i m correct here?

Comment: kubectl describe services sv-premier

Name:                     sv-premier
Namespace:           default
Labels:  
Annotations:              
Selector:                 app=sv-premier
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.105.63.249
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31678/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.45:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Comment: Moreover, I have just pulled the image from GCR. but deploying it onto local Kubernetes Cluster. Do i need to use LoadBalancer in that case

Comment: if you are deploying it on local cluster you need to use NodePort or proxy as you like.

Comment: Thanks DT. for looking into the issue. The CMD and ENTRYPOINT of dockerfile is overridden by command and args of Deployment file.  have to use multiple commands in deployment file so that it do not overrides. Multiple as in - EntryPoint and CMD of dockerfile in deployment.yaml. Will try to figure it how to do so.